# Single-spaced multi-line marginalia

Tags: line-spacing, marginpar, notes, color

When writing papers, I like to keep track of notes, thoughts and to do's inside the documents.

I'd love to have tiny coloured multi-line marginalia. So far I used sth like

```
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\marginpar{\begin{spacing}{0.8}\textcolor{red}{\scriptsize{#1}}\end{spacing}}}
```

to have a red side-note, but the single-spacing does not work. How can I have this marginalia single-spaced (or less)? And is it possible to have the text with a yellow background? The `\colorbox{}` command doesn't seem to wrap the text.

I'd also be interested how you keep track of notes and thoughts within your documents...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm which packages you're using.  It looks like `setspace` and some version of `color`, `xcolor`, `xxcolor` ...

Comment: Have you considered using the [`todonotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) package?

Comment: sure, sorry I missed out on that:

`hyperref,color,graphicx,setspace,natbib,bibgerm,ulem`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\setstretch` and `\parbox` inside `\colorbox`. Here's an example, using even smaller stretch value to make the effect more visible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{%
  \marginpar{\colorbox{yellow}{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{%
  \setstretch{0.5}\textcolor{red}{\scriptsize{#1}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\mymarginnote{Some text in the margin spanning several lines}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Yup, that's it, great! ;-)

Thanks, Stefan and the others! Esp. todonotes is worth a look for more complex projects!

stackexchange ftw!

Answer (score 4):

I think the *real* problem is this.

Wrong spacing:

```
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\marginpar{\textcolor{red}{\scriptsize #1}}}
```

Right spacing:

```
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\marginpar{\scriptsize\textcolor{red}{#1}}}
```

Explanation: In the second version, `\scriptsize` is still in effect when the paragraph ends. This is the point at which Latex chooses the line spacing for the paragraph.

No need to use any extra tweaks like the "spacing" environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `\linespread`, e.g.,

```
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{%
  {\linespread{0.85}\normalfont\scriptsize%
   \oldmarginpar[\vspace{-1.5ex}\raggedright\scriptsize\color{red}\textsf{#1}]%
                {\vspace{-1.5ex}\raggedright\scriptsize\color{green}\textsf{#1}}%
  }%
}
```

Of course, just adjust the `\linespread` factor to tighten things up (note that it's tucked inside a new `{...}` group).  To make things interesting, I've redefined `\marginpar` to show that you can format each side differently in `twoside` docs.  While I was at it, I adjusted the vertical position of the margin note up a notch to better align its baseline with the body text it relates to.  I omitted the `\colorbox` command you were interested in since Stefan's answer made its usage pretty clear.